# Excel formula, count occurrences in the first week

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find a way to display in a pivot table how many occurrences of specific product that happened in his first week of appearance. Below is the table's model. It's not that simple, but a valid example, I have something around 200k rows (I can't use SQL or any other software).

| Date Received | Week | Year | Product | Factory | Manufactury Date | Expiration Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | 48 | 2022 | Y | A | 10/10/2022 | 10/10/2023 |
| 02/06/2023 | 22 | 2023 | X | A | 10/10/2022 | 10/10/2023 |
| 03/06/2023 | 22 | 2023 | X | A | 10/10/2022 | 10/10/2023 |
| 10/06/2023 | 23 | 2023 | X | A | 10/10/2022 | 10/10/2023 |
| 10/06/2023 | 23 | 2023 | X | A | 10/10/2022 | 10/10/2023 |
| 22/06/2023 | 25 | 2023 | Y | A | 10/10/2022 | 10/10/2023 |

It should be something like this on pivot table, and when I click on number 2 or 1 it should list all occurrences:

| Manufactury | Product | Manufactury Date | occurrences first week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 10/10/2022 | 2 |
| A | Y | 10/10/2022 | 1 |

I know how to find the first occurrences; it would be something like this:

In a specific column a formula for concatenate:

```
=CONCATENATE('Product' & 'Factory' & 'Manufactury Date' & 'Expiration Date')
```

And in another cell a formula to count the concatenate formula and check if it is the first occurrences:

```
=IF(
    COUNT.IF(
'CONCATENATECOLUMNHERE': 'Z LINE OF CONCATENATECOLUMNHERE'
    ),
{ 'Z LINE OF CONCATENATECOLUMNHERE'
    ) > 1
),
{ "MORE THAN 1 OCCURRENCE"
),
{ 'FIRST OCCURRENCE'
)
```

I'm really trying to find a way to count only the oldest week for a specific product, but I can't find a way.

Comment: Sounds like you want to count how many rows of same product got date received value between MIN date received and MIN date received+7....

Answer (score 4):

There is no way you can calculate that directly in the Pivot table itself.

You could add a field on your source data to check if that row would be inside the first 7 days of a product:

[image]

I did field `test` using an array formula but I'm pretty sure it's easier on Excel365:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=MIN(IF($D$2:$D$7=D2;$A$2:$A$7));A2<=(MIN(IF($D$2:$D$7=D2;$A$2:$A$7))+6));1;0)
```

Because it's an array formula it must be entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or it won't work!

With this new field then use it as a filter in your pivot table:

[image]

**UPDATE:** When OP said *first week of appearance* meaned the first natural week of the date, not a period of 7 days. so the updated array formula is:

```
=IF(YEAR(A2)&WEEKNUM(A2;2)=YEAR(MIN(IF($D$2:$D$7=D2;$A$2:$A$7)))&WEEKNUM(MIN(IF($D$2:$D$7=D2;$A$2:$A$7));2);1;0)
```

This formula will compare the year and week number of each `Date received` versus the year and week number of the minimun `Date received` for each product. Then make the pivot table as explained before.

[image]

Test replacing `03/06/2023` with `05/06/2023` (both dates are on different weeks):

[image]

Notice I'm using [WEEKNUM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340) setting Monday as first day of week, but you can change this based on your needs.

Also, it's mandatory to check the year value because different years can have same date in same week number, but it wouldn't be really the same week.

Comment: Thank you. This works partially, the problem is that you are implying that "Date Received" will always be a monday, which is not true. So A2 must be between the first monday and sunday.

Comment: What do you mean with *you are implying that "Date Received" will always be a monday* ? Why does it work partially? It gets your desired output according to the data provided

Comment: 02/06/2023 and 03/06/2023 are actually in the same week. If you change 03/06/2023 to 05/06/2023 it shouldn't give you 1, but actually 0, because 05/06/2023 takes place in the next week of 02/06/2023. In summary, the week of 02/06/2023 is between 29/05/2023 and 04/06/2023, and 05/06/2023 isnt in the same week of 02/06/2023, so it should be 0, not 1.

Comment: Thank you so much. Last question: let's suppose that my database has 200k rows, how can I improve the update speed? I mean, I usually run a daily VBA as ETL, and arrays formulas makes my file 10x slower. Should I split the array formulas into different cells? Unfortunately the company doesn't allow me to use anything but excel.

Comment: That question is out of scope but with 200k rows probably you need to work on [manual mode](https://www.causal.app/excel/understanding-manual-calculation)